# Getting mod_rewrite to pass $_GET params?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, get

There's a couple other questions on this same topic on here that I've read, but mine is slightly different.  I'm trying to do a very basic mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^go/([^/\.]+)/?$ /go.php?page=$1
```

`go.php` looks like this:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    echo 'page='.$_GET['page'];
}else{
    echo 'oh shnizzle!';
}
?>
```

Now, when I go to `/go/someword` in my browser, the `$_GET` param "someword" IS NOT passed along, and I get the message "oh shnizzle!" every time.  What are possible reasons I'm not able to pass any `$_GET` params through mod_rewrite?

Comment: I don't seem to have a problem with the code... only thing I had to do was change `/go.php?page=$1` to a relative address `go.php?page=$1`.

Comment: hmm. I just changed mine to a relative address, and still doesn't work... got my usual result: "on shnizzle!"  Anyone know if there is a global config option for mod_rewrite that I'm not aware of? (maybe something is turned off on my server?)

Answer (score 13):

You probably have `MultiViews` turned on. Add this to the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

And the problem should go away, hopefully.

To elaborate a little on what's going on if this is the case, your URL `/go/someword` points to a non-existent resource, so `MultiViews` transforms it into `/go.php`, which does exist. When this happens, the `/somewhere` bit is passed to PHP as `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`, but `go.php` doesn't match your rewrite rule, so the rewrite is not performed to write that query string.

Comment: Excellent! Yes, this is it.  The rewrite is working perfectly fine now, and the $_GET params are coming through.  Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

You need the QSA (query string append) flag on your rewrite rule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^go/([^/\.]+)/?$ /go.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: I should also mention that when I use [QSA], a normal query string doesn't get passed along either.  Do you know if there are specific mod_rewrite config settings that completely turn off GET all-together?

Comment: This isn't what QSA fixes - that simply allows any query string on the original url to get put into the rewritten URL

Comment: Paul, you're right - sorry, didn't read the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/go/([^/\.]+)/?$ /go.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

This should stop the mod_rewrite rules from being triggered if a valid page, script or directory is requested. It will also append any existing Query Strings.

In the **go.php** file, I would have the following:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
echo '<b>$_GET Variables</b><pre>';
var_dump( $_GET );
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

That way, rather than looking for a specific variable (at least until it behaves itself) you can see exactly what GET variables are being passed to the script.