# $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] shows different after writing .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

This is our site actual url

http://www.globalmedicalaware.com/gma-new/home.php?city=Chennai

i rewrite the url by using .htaccess following code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /city/(.*) home.php?city=$1
```

Now the url rewrite to

http://www.globalmedicalaware.com/gma-new/home/city/Chennai

i written the code in column-right.php and in some other area like footer,..etc,.. this

```
if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']=='/gma-new/home.php') {

------------   some designs and action to display the column right for home.php only -----------

 }
```

in localhost for `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` shows `/gma-new/home.php`  correctly..

but in live site  for `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` shows `city/Chennai`..so column right coding for home.php not working..

please help me with this..

Comment: see ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223035/getting-mod-rewrite-to-pass-get-params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this instead in the .htaccess file at root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !home\.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^gma-new/home/city/([^/]+)/?  /gma-new/home.php?city=$1  [L,NC]
```

Maps silently:
`http://www.globalmedicalaware.com/gma-new/home/city/Chennai` to
`http://www.globalmedicalaware.com/gma-new/home.php?city=Chennai`

Where *Chennai* is a dynamic string.

For permanent and visible redirection, replace [L,NC] with [R=301,L,NC]

Comment: but i did the modification like this

Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !home\.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ home/city/([^/]+)/?  /gma-new/home.php?city=$1  [L,NC]

Answer (score 0):

Try to review it in http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php and I think you can subtitule `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` such this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/gma-new/home.php') {
    /*
    some designs and action to display the column right for home.php only
    */
}
```

Comment: Hi Servant..i am also tried that $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']..
For $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] it shows gma-new/home/city/Chennai
For $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] it shows city/Chennai
For $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] it shows www.globalmedicalaware.com..

Comment: Try to change your rewriting rule from `RewriteRule /city/(.*) home.php?city=$1` to `RewriteRule ^gma-new/home/city/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$ /gma-new/home.php?city=$1` and try to check if the problem is in the `.htaccess` file by disabling it temporarily in any way and check your issue if it persist.

Comment: Hi servant..i used $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']..now it is working fine..any way thank u.