# How to get URL Parameters after changing htaccess to clean URLs?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters, url-rewriting

I have URL Rewriting Activated:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^publisher/([^/\.]+)/?$ /publisher.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

I want to take the parameters from this URL via $ _GET:

https://website.com/publisher/2/

When I do the following...

```
$id = $_GET["page"];

echo "ID:". $id;
```

... My results stay empty and there is no output

I tried the following steps, other community members already recommended:

[Getting mod_rewrite to pass $_GET params?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223035/getting-mod-rewrite-to-pass-get-params)

Why can not I get on here? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: After adding

```
Options -MultiViews
```

it works fine but now I have anothe problem: Everytime I go to another page via a link I get a 300: Multiple Options.
https://website.com/test/ --> 300: /test.php/

Comment: So just to be clear, you actually tried to disable MultiViews, yes? _Show us_ what exactly you tried, don’t refer to other questions and give us just a “tried everything, nothing worked” - that is not helpful as a problem description.

Comment: Okay. My mistake. I did not put `Options -MultiViews` at the top. Just behind other options.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

Put this at your FIRST line and before other options:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Answer (score -1):

This rewrite condition changes only the url not the data. Remove ?php=$1 because this is only url not a real get data.

Comment: Still not working. I want to stay with that clean URL if possible. I just can't get the parameter :(